# How could a bilinear form with positive coefficients fail to be an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

So to prove somethings an inner product it has to be all positive terms.
But why do not all such expressions with positive coefficients define inner products?

For example, how is
$$\left<u,v\right> = x_1y_1 + 2x_1y_2 + x_2y_1 + 3x_2y_2$$
not an inner product?

Comment: **meant to say <x,y>= = x1y1 + 2*x1y2 + x2y1 + 3*x2y2

Answer (score 3):

$$\langle (1,0), (1,0)\rangle = 0, \qquad (1,0) \neq {\bf 0}.$$

It could be degenerate, like the above example shows.

Comment: doesnt <(1,0),(1,0)>=1 though?

Comment: No. Every term in the sum have at least one $y_i$, and here $y_1 = y_2 = 0 $.

Comment: I guess James Rajesh meant $u = (x_1, x_2)$, $v = (y_1, y_2)$, otherwise the expression wouldn't even be a bilinear form.

Answer (score 0):

If you drop the requirement of positive-definiteness, you can define many scalar products $\langle\mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle=(\mathbf v,A\mathbf u)$, where $A$ is a symmetric matrix and $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the Euclidean scalar product. These scalar products are closely related to quadratic forms.

Comment: so how do you get A?

Comment: $A$ is an arbitrary symmetric matrix that then defines a scalar product $(\mathbf v,A\mathbf u)$. Going in the other direction, it’s not too hard to compute $A$ directly from a bilinear symmetric form, or you can use the associated quadratic form $\langle\mathbf v,\mathbf v\rangle$ and read the entries of $A$ from the coefficients. The squared terms correspond to the diagonal elements and the cross terms to the off-diagonals.